# How to timeout Kotlin Flows if they take too long to emit first value

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have a listener that may never be called. But, if it is called at least once, I'm reasonably sure that it will be called many more times. I'm a fan of Flows, so I've wrapped it in a callbackFlow() builder. To guard against waiting forever, I want to add a time out. I'm trying to build flow operator that will throw TimeOut of some kind if the first element of the flow takes too long to be emitted. Here is what I have.

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.flowBeforeTimeout(ms: Long): Flow<T> = flow {
    withTimeout(ms){
        emit(first())
    }
    emitAll(this@flowBeforeTimeout.drop(1))
}
```

And it works a little, these JUnit4 tests pass. There are more passing tests, but I'm omitting them for brevity.

```
@Test(expected = CancellationException::class)
fun `Throws on timeout`(): Unit = runBlocking {
    val testFlow = flow {
        delay(200)
        emit(1)
    }

    testFlow.flowBeforeTimeout(100).toList()
}
```

```
@Test
fun `No distortion`(): Unit = runBlocking {
    val testList = listOf(1,2,3)

    val resultList = testList
        .asFlow()
        .flowBeforeTimeout(100)
        .toList()

    assertThat(testList.size, `is`(resultList.size))
}
```

However, this test is not passing.

```
// Fails with: Expected: is <1> but: was <2>
@Test
fun `Starts only once`(): Unit = runBlocking {
    var flowStartCount = 0

    val testFlow = flow {
        flowStartCount++
        emit(1)
        emit(2)
        emit(3)
    }

    testFlow.flowBeforeTimeout(100).toList()
    assertThat(flowStartCount, `is`(1))
}
```

Is there a way to prevent the flow from restarting between `first()` and `emitAll()`?

Answer (score 3):

This outcome is suggested by the `drop(1)` you needed in the implementation of the operator. Because you're using `withTimeout`, here's what your `flow` does:

- it starts the outer Flow until the first emission occurs;
- if it occurs within the timeout, it cancels the job and runs the outer flow a second time;
  Here's why the first emission happens twice.

I stumbled into your same challenge and wrote this operator. It might not be the most efficient code in the world but it's stateless and it passes all your tests. Let me know what you think.

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.flowBeforeTimeout(duration: Long): Flow<T> =
    combine(
        booleanTimer(duration), // emits false at flow start, then true after duration
        onStart<T?> { emit(null) } // emits null at flow start
    ) { hasTimedOut, value ->
        if (hasTimedOut && value == null) {
            throw CancellationException("Flow timed out after $duration ms.")
        } else {
            value
        }
    }.filterNotNull() // necessary because of the null emitted at flow start
    .distinctUntilChanged() // necessary because of the duplicate value emitted when hasTimedOut is true

private fun booleanTimer(duration: Long): Flow<Boolean> =
    flow {
        emit(false)
        delay(duration)
        emit(true)
    }
```